# Scrolling RecyclerView with custom interpolator and duration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to find a solution how to customize `RecyclerView` scrolling on a total different approach than most posts have e.g. using custom `LinearSmoothScroller` and modifying the speed per pixel.

First of all I want to use any `Interpolator` I want.

Secondly I want the duration to be static, no matter if the deltaY is 40 pixels or 4 million pixels.

With `ScrollView` the wanted behaviour was easy to produce using `ValueAnimator` with custom `Interpolator` and on the `onAnimationUpdate` callback just set the scroll Y. I am not able to find same solution with `RecyclerView`.

Reference code with `ScrollView`

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(
    mScrollView.getScrollY(), 0).setDuration(500);
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        mScrollView.setScrollY((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});

animator.start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: so if `LinearSmoothScroller` does not fit your needs create a custom `RecyclerView.SmoothScroller` that implements your own logic

Comment: @pskink Figured so but with first glance it seems that the scroller is designed to scroll in parts. So if the content height is high it will take multiple cycles to scroll for example from bottom to top. Need to check it more closely through.

Comment: it has to `"scroll in parts"`, otherwise it would block the UI thread, basically see the sources of [LinearSmoothScroller](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/support/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSmoothScroller.java)